# extract file names from a folder based on conditions

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a folder which has files  with the following contents.

```
ATOM      9  CE1 PHE A   1      70.635  -26.989  98.805  1.00 39.17           C  
ATOM     10  CE2 PHE A   1      69.915  -26.416 100.989  1.00 42.21           C  
ATOM     11  CZ  PHE A   1     -69.816   26.271 -99.622  1.00 40.62           C  
ATOM     12  N   PRO A   2     -69.795   30.848 101.863  1.00 44.44           N
```

In some files, the appearance of the 7th column as follows.

```
ATOM      9  CE1 PHE A   1      70.635-26.989  98.805   1.00 39.17             C  
ATOM     10  CE2 PHE A   1      69.915-26.416  100.989  1.00 42.21             C  
ATOM     11  CZ  PHE A   1     -69.816-26.271  -99.622  1.00 40.62             C  
ATOM     12  N   PRO A   2     -69.795-30.848  101.863  1.00 44.44             N
```

I would like to extract the name of files which have the above type of lines. What is the easy way to do this?

Comment: dirty and quick, but not sure will work 100% as expected. you could give it a try: `awk 'NF!=12{print FILENAME;nextfile}' /path/*`

Comment: @kent,@eleena replace FILENAME with $3 if file name is CE1.

Comment: What do you actually want to do? This is misformatted pdb format, so I'm guessing you want to repair wrong entries? Since pdb has fixed column widths, it would be easier to use sed and count the characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of grep and cut works for me:

```
grep -H -m 1 '\s-\?[0-9.]\+-[0-9.]\+\s' dir/* | cut -d: -f1
```

This performs the following steps:

- for every file in `dir/*`, find the first match (`-m 1`) of two adjacent numbers separated by only a dash
- print it with the filename prepended (`-H`). Should be the default anyway.
- extract the file name using `cut`

This is fast since it only looks for the first <strike>line</strike> match. If there's other places with two adjacent numbers, consider changing the regex.

Edit:

This doesn't match scientific notation and may falsely report contents such as '.-.', for example in comments. If you're dealing with one of them, you have to expand the regex.

Answer (score 3):

by refering to Erik E. Lorenz answer
you can simply do

```
grep -l '\s-\?[0-9.]\+-[0-9.]\+\s' dir/*
```

from grep manpage

```
-l
(The letter ell.) Write only the names of files containing selected
lines to standard output. Pathnames are written once per file searched.
If the standard input is searched, a pathname of (standard input) will
be written, in the POSIX locale. In other locales, standard input may be
replaced by something more appropriate in those locales.
```

Comment: The `-m 1` is redundant with `-l`.

Comment: Also I'm not entirely convinced that `\s` is portable.  Maybe replace with `[[:blank:]]` or `\<` / `\>`?

Comment: from [gnu grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) **‘\s’**
**Match whitespace, it is a synonym for ‘[[:space:]]’.**

Comment: Sure, but is it POSIX?

Comment: No it is'nt , the backslash is NOT a metacharacter in a POSIX bracket expression [see](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58364/discussion-between-bachn-and-tripleee).

Comment: Nice `-l` option. Haven't heard about it before :-) About \s: Just leave it out to be sure. The expression works without \s, too, if the file itself is otherwise in an otherwise PDB-compliant format.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NF > 10 && $1 ~ /^[[:upper:]]+$/ && $2 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+/ { print FILENAME; nextfile }' *
```

Will print files that have more than 10 fields in which first field is all uppercase letters and second field is all digits.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for `nextfile`:

```
awk '$7 ~ /[0-9]-[0-9]/{print FILENAME; nextfile}' *
```

or more efficiently since you just need to test the first line of each file if all lines in a given file have the same format:

```
awk 'FNR==1{if ($7 ~ /[0-9]-[0-9]/) print FILENAME; nextfile}' *
```